# can't "convert" pandas column into non-decimal int after concatenating

Tags: python, pandas, int, decimal

I'm trying to do something extremely simple, but I'm fairly new to pandas and I can't seem to work it out. I'm loading a csv with several columns:

1. id
2. house number
3. street
4. town
5. postcode

I need to output the same thing, but house_number, street and town should be concatenated in one address column, meaning I will output:

1. id
2. address
3. postcode

My house numbers are **integers in the CSV**, but for some reason, when I load it into pandas, it converts the column to string (some values are missing, that's understandable). I can't seem to get the numbers to be integers when exporting or printing, **pandas automatically adds a decimal** to them, which is incredibly annoying and useless. My address becomes 33.0 Street Name, Town. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

csv = 'C:\\test\\input.csv'

read = pd.read_csv(csv)

cols = ['id', 'address', 'postcode']
subset = [read['id'], read['house_number'].map(str) + ' ' + read['street'].map(str) + ' ' + read['town'].map(str), read['postcode']]

data = pd.concat(subset, axis=1, keys=cols)

display(data)
data.to_csv('C:\\test\\output.csv')
```

Any advice on how to make sure those house numbers stay house numbers? I don't even understand why pandas adds a decimal if the column type is automatically string, not anything numeric.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like missing values are the bane here. From [pandas nullable integer type documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

> In Working with missing data, we saw that pandas primarily uses NaN to represent missing data. Because NaN is a float, this forces an array of integers with any missing values to become floating point. In some cases, this may not matter much. But if your integer column is, say, an identifier, casting to float can be problematic. Some integers cannot even be represented as floating point numbers.

And it seems, this should be useful for you :

```
arr = pd.array([1, 2, None], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
pd.Series(arr) ## pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Although the documentation does warn that it's experimental, and could change.

So, to be safe you would probably want to impute the `null` values then cast as `int` and `string` consecutively!